# application for re-entry to the UK

Tags: visas, uk

I was in the UK from 2004-2008 and was removed in 2008. I guess i got a 10yr ban but not sure as no papers was given to me to state this. I wish to return to the UK to see my daughter for the first time since she was born in 2008, the very year I was removed.
I've only seen her in pictures and video calls and I want to go see her as shes 11yrs old now.

Do I have a chance of success if I apply? Also how can I check if Iwas banned or not as I dont even know if i was.

Comment: If you had a ban, you should have been informed in writing. Check your old papers, post them here **with all personal information blanked out**. If there is no ban, that does not mean any new application from you would be granted. They will scrutinize it very carefully. Your daughter could visit you (together with her legal guardian), not the other way around, so this personal story will not help *much*.

Comment: thanks for your response....unfortunately i dont have any papers as regarding this.......and if i decide to apply, should i mentioned i was removed in the application? because someone said to me that after 10yrs, such records would have been wiped off the system......

Comment: @chris kent What are your personal circumstances like now? Do you have a good travel history to equivalent jurisdictions such as US, Schengen etc and strong ties to your home country? As the answers state, your removal is a major obstacle, possibly not insurmountable but only if you can present an impeccable application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you were removed you were almost certainly given papers stating what was happening and why. It is unfortunate that you did not keep them.

Being removed does not always attract a ten year ban, but it may have done. In any case a ten year ban would now have expired. But that does not mean you will be admitted. The UK does not give bans longer than ten years.

It is not true that your record is wiped after ten years. What is true is that you are not asked about refusals more than ten years old. However immigration will still know that you were removed and the fact will be taken into account. A removal is a major obstacle to getting a visa because it shows you have been willing to break immigration law in the past.

Having a daughter in the UK will not help your chances of getting a UK visitor visa as it gives you a reason to stay in the UK after the end of your visa.

By far the easiest way of your getting to see your daughter is to have her and her other parent come and visit you outside the UK.

Comment: thanks for your responses. at present, i own a company here in South Africa and doing quite well. Although ive not travelled anywhere else, so would you suggest i travel to various countries to get a good travel history before applying for a UK visa?